# Class template specialization in class scope?

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class, specialization

Why is the specialization S in A legal and S in B not?

( if B is not commented out )
GCC 4.8.1: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class B’

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class Y {};
class X {};

struct A {
  template<class T, class = void>
  class S;

  template<class T>
  struct S < T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< Y, T >::value >::type > 
  {
    int i = 0;
  };

  template<class T>
  struct S < T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< X, T >::value >::type > 
  {
    int i = 1;
  };
};

/*
class B
{
    template<class T>
    class S;

    template<>
    class S < Y > {};

    template<>
    class S < X > {};
};
*/


int main()
{
    A::S< X > asd;
    std::cout << asd.i << std::endl;
}
```

[on coliru: B commented out](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d2c0ad8baeec7d8)

[on coliru: with B (error)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7524fe06f22f933b)

Comment: You can have partial specializations in non-namespace scope, but not explicit specializations.

Comment: @jrok Could you elaborate? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19861791/725863) answer does not seem to agree.

Answer (score 13):

The comments by @jrok pretty much explains your compiler error. Nested classes in general, and nested class templates in particular, are a dusty corner of the language that you can easily avoid (taking to heart Sutter's advice "[Write what you know and know what you write](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/advice97.htm)").

Simply make a `namespace detail` to define your class templates `SA` and `SB` and their specializations and then define a nested template type alias `S` inside both `A` and `B`

```
namespace detail {

  template<class T, class = void>
  class SA;

  template<class T>
  struct SA < T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< Y, T >::value >::type > 
  {
    int i = 0;
  };

  template<class T>
  struct SA < T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< X, T >::value >::type > 
  {
    int i = 1;
  };

  template<class T>
  class SB;

  template<>
  class SB < Y > {};

  template<>
  class SB < X > {};
}

struct A
{
    template<class T>
    using S = detail::SA<T>;
};

struct B
{
    template<class T>
    using S = detail::SB<T>;
};
```

Granted, for this case it might seem overkill, but if you ever want to make `A` and `B` class templates themselves, and specialize `A` and `B`, then you can only specialize the nested class templates if you also specialize the enclosing class. In short: just avoid these issues altogether by an extra level of compile-time indirection.

Comment: I believe that the using statements are incorrect, and should look like this:

    template<class T>
    using S = detail::SA<T>;

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias