# Where to declare partial specializations of class member templates?

Tags: c++, templates

Here on stackoverflow I've found several comments (see for example the comment by [jrok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947836/jrok) on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904587/class-template-specialization-in-class-scope) question) stating that partial specializations of class member templates are allowed at non-namespace scope (in contrast to explicit specializations) like in the example below:

```
class A {
    template <class T, class U>
    class B {};
    template <class U>
    class B<void, U> {};
};
```

Also, this example compiles just fine with both gcc and clang. However in the c++03 standard text I can only find 14.5.4 [temp.class.spec] §6 (or 14.5.5 §5 in c++11) about this issue:

> A class template partial specialization may be declared or redeclared in any namespace scope in which its definition may be defined (14.5.1 and 14.5.2).

Along with the following example:

```
template<class T> struct A {
    class C {
        template<class T2> struct B { };
    };
};

// partial specialization of A<T>::C::B<T2>
template<class T> template<class T2>
struct A<T>::C::B<T2*> { };
```

So, how about class template partial specializations at non-namespace scope? Are they allowed by the standard? And where can I find the relevant text?

Specifically, is my example valid (and would it still be valid if the enclosing class would be a template)? If not, are current compilers wrong to compile my example as stated above?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bit confusing, as I agree the paragraph you quoted seems to disallow partial specializations inside class definitions. However, there's [temp.class.spec.mfunc]/2:

> If a member template of a class template is partially specialized, the
>   member template partial specializations are member templates of the
>   enclosing class template; [...] [*Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct A {
>     template<class T2> struct B {}; // #1
>     template<class T2> struct B<T2*> {}; // #2
> };
>
> template<> template<class T2> struct A<short>::B {}; // #3
>
> A<char>::B<int*> abcip; // uses #2
> A<short>::B<int*> absip; // uses #3
> A<char>::B<int> abci; // uses #1
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

IMHO this isn't very explicit; it doesn't *allow* partial specialization inside the class definition but rather (to me, seems to) specifies how member template specializations are treated.

---

Also see the [Core Language Issue 708](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#708) and [EWG Issue 41](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3566.html#41).

Comment: I find this answer very unsatisfactory :( but it's too long for a comment.

Comment: I had already noticed this as well. However, it doesn't actually answer the question, despite the example provided by the standard. I can add it to my question if you want.

Comment: About [Core Language Issue 708](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#708): it seems to me the correct behaviour is specified by the exact paragraph you quoted in your answer. Or am I missing something?