# explicit template specialization in G++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, g++

I have errors in this code (g++ compiler), but in MSVS is compiling good. Please help to solve this problem.

code:

```
template<class t_Struct, typename T_Xerializer>
    struct FindXerializer
    {
        template <int>
        struct ImplementedXerializer;

        template <>
        struct ImplementedXerializer<1>
        {
            static void load_struct(CTicDbxJob& job, t_Struct& aResult)
            {
                T_Xerializer x(aResult);
                try
                {
                    CTICSerializer::Load(x, job.getTicOptions().internal_getFieldsStore());
                    aResult = x;
                }
                catch(IFieldsStore::baddata_exception&)
                {
                    aResult = t_Struct();
                }
            }
        }
    }



template<class t_Struct, class T_Xerializer>
    bool Xerializer<t_Struct, T_Xerializer>::load_struct(CTicDbxJob& job, t_Struct& aResult)
    {
        FindXerializer<t_Struct, T_Xerializer>::ImplementedXerializer<CanXerialize<T_Xerializer>::Yes >::load_struct(job, aResult);
        return true;
    }

    template<class t_Struct, class T_Xerializer>
    bool Xerializer<t_Struct, T_Xerializer>::save_struct(CTicDbxJob& job, const t_Struct& aData)
    {
        FindXerializer<t_Struct, T_Xerializer>::ImplementedXerializer<CanXerialize<T_Xerializer>::Yes >::save_struct(job, aData);
        return true;
    }
```

errors:

**error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct TicDbx::FindXerializer'**

**error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
         struct ImplementedXerializer<1>**

I DONE IT!!!!
here the solution:

```
template <class t_Struct, class T_Xerializer, int>
    struct ImplementedXerializer
    {
    };

    template <class t_Struct, class T_Xerializer>
    struct ImplementedXerializer<t_Struct, T_Xerializer, 1>
    {
        static void load_struct(CTicDbxJob& job, t_Struct& aResult)
        {
            T_Xerializer x(aResult);
            .....
        }

        static void save_struct(CTicDbxJob& job, const t_Struct& aData)
        {
            .....
        }
    };

    template <class t_Struct, class T_Xerializer>
    struct ImplementedXerializer<t_Struct, T_Xerializer, 0>
    {
        static t_Struct& get_static()
        {
            .....
        }

        static void load_struct(CTicDbxJob& job, t_Struct& aResult)
        {
            ....
        }

        static void save_struct(CTicDbxJob& job, const t_Struct& aData)
        {
            .....
        }
    };
            ^


template<class t_Struct, class T_Xerializer>
    bool Xerializer<t_Struct, T_Xerializer>::load_struct(CTicDbxJob& job, t_Struct& aResult)
    {
        .....
    }

    template<class t_Struct, class T_Xerializer>
    bool Xerializer<t_Struct, T_Xerializer>::save_struct(CTicDbxJob& job, const t_Struct& aData)
    {
        .....

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904587/class-template-specialization-in-class-scope

Comment: I dont understand what i must to write, please help with this problem?

Comment: In short, you cannot do what you want as a nested class. You need to put your class outside, or change the design. See the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3052579/1147772

Comment: I updated my questions. Where I must to use this static functions.

Comment: @user3749207 then, why don't you just put `ImplementedXerializer` into global namespace?

Comment: @ikh, this code was imported from visual studio project.

Comment: @user3749207 whether you imported or not, you can just move it global namespace; And although you use VC++, you should follow C++ standard - otherwise something like this error happens..

Comment: If you get it, you can answer yourself and accept it.